# MediaWiki invoke image not working

Tags: c#, mediawiki-templates

I'm trying to invoke an image with infobox and infoboxImage.  Here is what I have....

```
|image = {{#invoke:InfoboxImage|InfoboxImage|image={{{image|}}}|size={{{image_size|}}}|upright=  {{{image_upright|1}}}|alt={{{alt|}}}}}
```

And I get the following error on my index.php?title=Module:InfoboxImage&action=submit#mw-ce-l1 page

```
 Script error: Lua error at line 1: unexpected symbol near '|'.
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Here is my LocalSettings.php for Scribunto:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Scribunto/Scribunto.php";
#$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = "luastandalon"';
```

Comment: Why the [tag:c#] tag?

Answer (score 0):

So you're adding template syntax like `{{{image|}}}` in a module page? Why?

I doubt you really need to handle such a Lua module for your wiki. However, if you really want to copy the Lua-powered infobox templates of other wikis, make sure you [import them](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Import) with Special:Import and select the recursive import checkbox.

Hopefully you'll then have all the modules you need without fiddling with them.